# Get the position of a CGPoint( which is inside a subview), W.R.T the parentView - ObjectiveC

Tags: objective-c, uiview

I have a point inside a sub`UIView`. I want to find the location of that `CGPoint` with respect to the subview's parent `UIView`. How do I get it?

Comment: As easy as adding the origin from the parent view to that coordinate point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CGPoint pointInSuperview = [superview convertPoint:pointInSubview fromView:subView];
```

Example:

```
UIView *subView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 100)];
[self.view addSubview:subView];

CGPoint pointInSubview = CGPointMake(20, 20);
CGPoint pointInSuperview = [self.view convertPoint:pointInSubview fromView:subView];
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(pointInSuperview));
```

Prints out `{70, 70}` to the console